# How do you check if two pointers point to the same object?

Tags: c++, pointers, equality

Suppose I have 2 pointers:

```cpp
int *a = something;
int *b = something;
```

If I want to compare them and see if they point at the same object, does `a == b` work?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, that is the definition of [raw pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#raw_pointer) equality: they both point to the same location (or are [pointer aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)); usually in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running your application coded in C++ and managed by some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (but C++ can also be used for programming embedded devices with micro-controllers having a [Harward architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture): on such microcontrollers some pointer casts are forbidden and makes no sense - since read only data could sit in code ROM)

For C++, read [a good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website, read the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)) and consider coding with [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Maybe read also some draft C++ standard, like [n4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) or buy the official standard from your [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) representative.

The concepts and terminology of [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) are also relevant when managing pointers and memory zones obtained by dynamic allocation (e.g. `::operator new`), so read perhaps the [GC handbook](https://gchandlbook.org/).

For pointers on Linux machines, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871661/841108).

Comment: Pointer is (in layman's term) essentially a integer value for the memory address in your computer.  It is like comparing integers.

Comment: @KeminZhou: this is true on most current computers, but false in general. Even on the old 1980 PC AT 8086 it was false

Comment: Absolutely NOT.  In C++ operators are just arbitrary functions that can do what they please.  In particular, for strings == is a value comparison, not a string comparison.  For iterating through a stream it does very odd things.  This is a big trap for the unwary.  If you want to compare pointers, you need to cast to something.

Answer (score 128):

For a bit of *facts* here is the relevant text from the specifications

### Equality operator (==,!=)

Pointers to objects of the same type can be compared for equality with the 'intuitive' expected results:

From **§ 5.10**  of the C++11 standard:

> Pointers of the same type
>   (after pointer conversions) can be compared for equality. Two pointers of the same type compare equal if
>   and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address (*3.9.2*).
>
> *(leaving out details on comparison of pointers to member and or the null pointer constants - they continue down the same line of 'Do What I Mean':)*
>
> - [...] If both operands are null, they compare equal. Otherwise if only one is null, they compare unequal.[...]
>
> The most 'conspicuous' caveat has to do with virtuals, and it does seem to be the logical thing to expect too:
>
> - [...] if either is a pointer to a virtual member function, the result is unspecified. Otherwise they
>     compare equal if and only if they would refer to the same member of the same most derived object (1.8)
>     or the same subobject if they were dereferenced with a hypothetical object of the associated class type. [...]

### Relational operators (<,>,<=,>=)

From **§ 5.9** of the C++11 standard:

> Pointers to objects or functions of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared,
>   with a result defined as follows:
>
> 1. If two pointers p and q of the same type point to the same object or
>      function, or both point one past the end of the same array, or are both
>      null, then `p<=q` and `p>=q` both yield true and `p<q` and `p>q` both yield false.
> 2. If two pointers p and q of the same type point to different objects that **are
>      not members of the same object or elements of the same array** or to different
>      functions, or if only one of them is null, the results of `p<q,` `p>q,` `p<=q,` and
>      `p>=q` **are unspecified**.
> 3. If two pointers point to non-static data members of the same object, or to
>      subobjects or array elements of such members, recursively, the pointer to the
>      later declared member compares greater provided the two members have the same
>      access control (Clause 11) and provided their class is not a union.
> 4. If two pointers point to non-static data members of the same object with
>      different access control (Clause 11) the result is unspecified.
> 5. If two pointers point to non-static data members of the same union object,
>      they compare equal (after conversion to `void*`, if necessary). If two pointers
>      point to elements of the same array or one beyond the end of the array, the
>      pointer to the object with the higher subscript compares higher.
> 6. Other pointer comparisons are unspecified.

So, if you had:

```
int arr[3];
int *a = arr;
int *b = a + 1;
assert(a != b); // OK! well defined
```

Also OK:

```
struct X { int x,y; } s;
int *a = &s.x;
int *b = &s.y;
assert(b > a); // OK! well defined
```

But it depends on the *`something`* in your question:

```
int g; 
int main()
{
     int h;
     int i;

     int *a = &g;
     int *b = &h; // can't compare a <=> b
     int *c = &i; // can't compare b <=> c, or a <=> c etc.
     // but a==b, b!=c, a!=c etc. are supported just fine
}
```

### Bonus: what else is there in the standard library?

**§ 20.8.5/8**: "For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type  yield a total order, even if the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` do not."

So, you can globally *order* any odd `void*` as long as you use `std::less<>` and friends, not bare `operator<`.

Comment: Would the `int *a = arr;` line benefit from including a reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694/address-of-array? I'm not sure if it is relevant enough to the question asked though...

Comment: Today, the inimitable @JerryCoffin made me aware of the fact that the standard library has more stringent specifications for the function object templates defined in `<functional>`. Added.

Comment: It seems that this chapter has changed in the ongoing C++ draft. Unless I misunderstand it, there is no more unspecified behavior: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername [Was still true in C++14 at least](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774802/560648)

Comment: Wrong.  "a" + "b" == "ab" is probably true, value comparson for strings.  Operators do what they want.  This is a big trap for the unwary.  There is no safe ptr operation.  And for streams == is particularly weird.

Comment: @Turntable I think you might have posted your comment somewhere you didn't intend?

Answer (score 25):

The `==` operator on pointers will compare their numeric address and hence determine if they point to the same object.

Comment: It's a little more complicated if multiple inheritance is involved.

Answer (score 23):

To sum up. If we want to see if two pointers point to the same memory location we can do that. Also if we want to compare the contents of the memory pointed to by two pointers we can do that too, just remeber to dereference them first.

If we have

```
int *a = something; 
int *b = something;
```

which are two pointers of the same type we can:

Compare memory address:

```
a==b
```

and compare contents:

```
*a==*b
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing pointers is not portable,
for example in DOS different pointer values points
to the same location, comparison
of the pointers returns false.

```
/*--{++:main.c}--------------------------------------------------*/
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
  int   val_a = 123;
  int * ptr_0 = &val_a;
  int * ptr_1 = MK_FP(FP_SEG(&val_a) + 1, FP_OFF(&val_a) - 16);

  printf(" val_a = %d -> @%p\n", val_a, (void *)(&val_a));
  printf("*ptr_0 = %d -> @%p\n", *ptr_0, (void *)ptr_0);
  printf("*ptr_1 = %d -> @%p\n", *ptr_1, (void *)ptr_1);

  /* Check what returns the pointers comparison: */
  printf("&val_a == ptr_0 ====> %d\n", &val_a == ptr_0);
  printf("&val_a == ptr_1 ====> %d\n", &val_a == ptr_1);
  printf(" ptr_0 == ptr_1 ====> %d\n",  ptr_0 == ptr_1);

  printf("val_a = %d\n", val_a);

  printf(">> *ptr_0 += 100;\n");
             *ptr_0 += 100;

  printf("val_a = %d\n", val_a);

  printf(">> *ptr_1 += 500;\n");
             *ptr_1 += 500;

  printf("val_a = %d\n", val_a);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
/*--{--:main.c}--------------------------------------------------*/
```

Compile it under Borland C 5.0, here is the result:

```
/*--{++:result}--------------------------------------------------*/
 val_a = 123 -> @167A:0FFE
*ptr_0 = 123 -> @167A:0FFE
*ptr_1 = 123 -> @167B:0FEE
&val_a == ptr_0 ====> 1
&val_a == ptr_1 ====> 0
 ptr_0 == ptr_1 ====> 0
val_a = 123
>> *ptr_0 += 100;
val_a = 223
>> *ptr_1 += 500;
val_a = 723
/*--{--:result}--------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: In end of 2020 or 2021, it is time to switch to better compilers like  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: In both clang and gcc, equality comparison between a pointer to one object and a pointer just past the end of an object that happens to immediately precede it in the address space--a scenario expressly addressed by the Standard--is prone to behave in a fashion which is consistent neither with the comparison yielding true nor with it comparing false.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the types of the values, and the way that operators happen to have been defined.  For example, string comparison is by value, not by address.  But char * is by address normally (I think).

A big trap for the unwary.  There is no guaranteed pointer comparison operator, but

```
  (void *)a == (void *)b
```

is probably fairly safe.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code to check pointer aliasing:

```
int main () {
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    int *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4;

    p1 = &a;
    p2 = &a;
    if(p1 == p2){
        std::cout<<"p1 and p2 alias each other"<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"p1 and p2 do not alias each other"<<std::endl;
    }
    //------------------------
    p3 = &a;
    p4 = &b;
    if(p3 == p4){
        std::cout<<"p3 and p4 alias each other"<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"p3 and p4 do not alias each other"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
p1 and p2 alias each other
p3 and p4 do not alias each other
```