# why accessing an address of a variable changes the address of another variable?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address

**Code 1:**

```
int main(){
   int a=1;
   int b=2;
   cout << "&a: "<<&a << endl;
}
```

**Output 1:**

```
&a: 0x22ff48
```

**Code 2:**

```
int main(){
   int a=1;
   int b=2;
   cout << "&a: "<<&a << endl;
   cout << "&b: "<<&b << endl;
}
```

**Output 2:**

```
&a: 0x22ff4c
&b: 0x22ff48
```

---

So My Question is why the address of the varibale `a` changed when I printed out the address of the varibale `b` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you didn't use `b` at all, the compiler probably removed it completely, so it didn't occupy any space.

When you took the address of `b`, that forced the compiler to allocate space for it.

Comment: In addition, it might not have eliminated it, but assigned it only to a register, since its address is never taken.

Comment: @DaveS: Certainly possible as well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin does this apply only if I access the address of variable b, because nothing changes in code1 if I print out the variable b, as if the compiler replaces b by it's value at compile time, and b didn't get allocated at all.

Comment: @AlexDan: Keep in mind we're only dealing in probabilities here. That said: yes, most compilers can eliminate the variable if it never varies. As DaveS pointed out, they can also assign them to registers if their address is never taken and there's nothing else more important to occupy the registers.

Answer (score 5):

Anyways, the OS is free to load the executable image at another (virtual) base address next time around.

What you are observing is *undefined* anyhow. The point is, **even** if no variables get optimized away, and the program doesn't get recompiled, it may yield different results each time.

It *may* be implementation defined, if you count the OS as part of the *implementation*

Comment: At least in a typical implementation, what's going to matter here isn't the load address of the executable image, but the base address of the stack (though, of course, that can vary as well).

Comment: I would call it "unspecified" rather than "undefined".  ;)

Comment: @Yakk In fact, it _is_ undefined. The standard doesn't specify it should be defined by the implementation. (Heck, the standard doesn't even specify that `&a` should represent an _address_ (logical or physical). It's just ... a "pointer", which is an abstraction. The standard **does** specify that 'pointers' must be deterministically comparable, in a number of limited situations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086372/how-to-compare-pointers/9086675#9086675)

Comment: Are you claiming that `int a=0;std::cout << &a;` could segfault on a conforming compiler?  I'd expect the value you get to be unspecified by the standard, but I would doubt that the behavior of streaming a pointer out is "undefined behavior".

Comment: @Yakk No. I didn't say that. The result will be implementation defined. But whether the result is the same on different runs of the identical code in "identical situation" (Heisenberg?) is _unspecified_