# making a shared_ptr weak

Tags: c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

I've got an map `shared_ptrs`

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<Target>> map;
```

Is there a way to make them `weak_ptrs` at some point or do I
have to make something like

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, 
    std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Target>, 
    std::weak_ptr<Target>>> map;
```

and swap them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always assign from `shared_ptr` to `weak_ptr`, they are complimentary parts of the same design. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Deduplicator I want to remove the reference shared_ptr puts on it so it might get deleted if there's no other shared_ptr somewhere. Basically I want to change the shared_ptr to a weak_ptr at runtime.

Comment: There's no way to make a `shared_ptr` act like a `weak_ptr` or the other way around. What would be the point of such an amorphous mass? Though what you *can* do is making a non-owning non-empty `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Christoph: Then you have to use a `std::pair` (or a custom `struct` that holds both types) and swap them when needed, eg: `auto &value = map[12345]; value.second = value.first; value.first.reset();` This assumes that there is another `shared_ptr` somewhere keeping the object alive, otherwise there is no point in assigning an object to a `weak_ptr` just to free the object when the associated `shared_ptr` is cleared.

Comment: How about using `boost::variant` instead ?

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping the point behind this question.  Does the `map` participate in ownership or not?  You appear to be mixing two concepts here...

Answer (score 2):

As people already stated in the comments, you can not do that. A `shared_ptr` always owns a reference, while a `weak_ptr` never does. The API of the standard library is explicitly designed in a way that the type tells you whether you currently own a reference or not (and the only thing you should do to access pointees of `weak_ptr` objects is `lock()` them, and check the resulting `shared_ptr` for non-null-ness, so you can (even in a multi-threaded environment) be sure, that you own a reference for yourself while working with the object.

What you could possibly do is have a map of `weak_ptr` all along, and store a `shared_ptr` elsewhere as long as you want to keep the object alive. Depending on the design or purpose, the place for the `shared_ptr` might even be a member variable of the object.

If you use a map of pairs, I would not swap() the pair members, but start with a pair of a shared and a weak ptr referring to the same managed object, and just reset() the shared ptr if it is decided to drop the strong reference, not touching the weak_ptr at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `weak_ptr` or `shared_ptr` itself as the key in the map. So indeed:

```
std::map<std::weak_ptr<void>, std::string> information_map;
```

Would be able to associate strings with **any** kind of weak ptr, regardless of type. This is because `std::less<void*>` defines a weak total ordering over all possible pointer values according to the standard.

See also

- [Advanced Shared Pointer Programming Techniques](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html)
- [How to compare pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086372/how-to-compare-pointers/9086675#9086675)