# string relational operator comparison vs string::compare() in cpp

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

In short I am getting different output for string comparison using string::compare() vs relational operator '<' on std::string class objects.

```
string str = "100";
cout << str.compare("10")<<endl; //prints 1
cout << ("100" < "10") <<endl; //prints 1
```

Here's the demo [url](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/2836e557-2107-4b81-b964-8963eea95340)

lexicographically "100" is greater than "10" and hence ("100" <"10") must print 0 since it's false but the output 1 i.e true is not expected.
The str.compare() function returns > 0 which is expected validating "100" > "10".
Why is this happening?

Comment: You are not comparing strings, you are comparing pointers. `"100" < "10"` could be true or false depending where the string literals are located in memory. Try `str < "10"`

Comment: Thank you @john. Got it. Is there any possible explanation for why I always get true for "100" < "10" for the above code on multiple machines, consistently?

Comment: Presumably that's dependent on the compiler you are using. I ran your code on my compiler and got `1 0` (and a compiler warning message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement

```
cout << ("100" < "10") <<endl;
```

you are comparing two pointers of the type `const char *` to which the used string literals are implicitly converted. The result of such a comparison is undefined (At least in the C Standard there is explicitly stated that such operation is undefined).

In fact the above statement is equivalent to

```
cout << ( &"100"[0] < &"10"[0] ) <<endl;
```

If you want to compare strings the you need to write at least like

```
cout << (std::string( "100" ) < "10") <<endl;
```

In this case the output will be

```
0
```

Pay attention to that according to the C++ 20 (7.6.9 Relational operators)

> 1. ...The comparison is deprecated if both operands were of array type prior to these conversions

And the both string literals prior to comparison have array types.

Comment: I think the result is only [unspecified, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774683/is-pointer-comparison-undefined-or-unspecified-behavior-in-c). Important because while you can't predict whether `("100" < "10")` will be `true` or `false`, it will be one of those two and not "the behavior of the entire enclosing program is undefined".

Comment: @NathanPierson According to the C Standard the behavior is undefined. In the C++ Standard there is written "Otherwise, neither pointer compares greater than the other.". So it is also undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanPierson It is interesting written in the C++ 20 Standard (7.6.9 Relational operators, p.4)  "— Otherwise, neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other.