# Spirit X3, ascii::cntrl why disparity with std::iscntrl?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm concentrating on checking for error conditions in an parser design using Spirit X3. One of which is the character category checks like `isalpha` or `ispunct`. According to the X3 documentation [Character Parsers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/char.html) they should match what C++ provides as `std::isalpha` and `std::ispunct`. However with a code demonstration shown below I do get different results.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/version.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace client::parser
{
  namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
  namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

  using ascii::char_;
  using ascii::space;
  using x3::skip;

  x3::rule<class main_rule_id, char> const main_rule_ = "main_rule";
  const auto main_rule__def = ascii::cntrl;

  BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE( main_rule_ ) 
  const auto entry_point = skip(space) [ main_rule_ ];
}

int main()
{
  printf( "Spirit X3 version: %4.4x\n", SPIRIT_X3_VERSION );

  char output;

  bool r = false;
  bool r2 = false; // answer according to default "C" locale
  char input[2];
  input[1] = 0;

  printf( "ascii::cntrl\n" );

  uint8_t i = 0;
  next_char:  
    input[0] = (char)i;
    r = parse( (char*)input, input+1, client::parser::entry_point, output );
    r2 = (bool)std::iscntrl( (unsigned char)i );
    printf( "%2.2x:%d%d", i, r, r2 );
    if ( i == 0x7f ) { goto exit_loop; }
    ++i;
    if ( i % 8 ) { putchar( ' ' ); } else { putchar( '\n' ); }
    goto next_char;
  exit_loop:

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Spirit X3 version: 3004
ascii::cntrl
00:11 01:11 02:11 03:11 04:11 05:11 06:11 07:11
08:11 09:01 0a:01 0b:01 0c:01 0d:01 0e:11 0f:11
10:11 11:11 12:11 13:11 14:11 15:11 16:11 17:11
18:11 19:11 1a:11 1b:11 1c:11 1d:11 1e:11 1f:11
20:00 21:00 22:00 23:00 24:00 25:00 26:00 27:00
28:00 29:00 2a:00 2b:00 2c:00 2d:00 2e:00 2f:00
30:00 31:00 32:00 33:00 34:00 35:00 36:00 37:00
38:00 39:00 3a:00 3b:00 3c:00 3d:00 3e:00 3f:00
40:00 41:00 42:00 43:00 44:00 45:00 46:00 47:00
48:00 49:00 4a:00 4b:00 4c:00 4d:00 4e:00 4f:00
50:00 51:00 52:00 53:00 54:00 55:00 56:00 57:00
58:00 59:00 5a:00 5b:00 5c:00 5d:00 5e:00 5f:00
60:00 61:00 62:00 63:00 64:00 65:00 66:00 67:00
68:00 69:00 6a:00 6b:00 6c:00 6d:00 6e:00 6f:00
70:00 71:00 72:00 73:00 74:00 75:00 76:00 77:00
78:00 79:00 7a:00 7b:00 7c:00 7d:00 7e:00 7f:11
```

So the first bit after the colon is the answer according to X3 and the second bit is the answer according to C++. The mismatch happens on the characters that also fall into the category `isspace`. Recently I'm more looking into the library headers, but I still haven't found a part that explains this behavior.

Why the disparity? Do I have missed something?

Oh yeah, I love my goto statements. And my retro C style. I hope you do too! Even for an X3 parser.

Comment: Hah. Noticed your comments about style late :) Oh well. Let's just say we have different opinions. I do like something like https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/format/doc/format.html or https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt but it's a bit out of scope for SO answering

Comment: I made an edit in my post. I removed a sentence: "Is this another bug in X3" while I was to blame for misusing the skipper facility.

Comment: @sehe about the C++ tag, okay that you add it but as this is so Spirit X3 specific, why would it be relevant for people with a general interest in C++?

Comment: It's just further defining an audience (tags can be language-agnostic). Also, it automatically causes syntax highlighting to become relevant to the language

Comment: If you want exactly `std::iscntrl` - you can use `x3::standard::cntrl` parser. The reason for the divergence is unknown to me, probably it is a good idea to open a bug report https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally run amok with the skipper which eats any whitespace before you can actually parse it.

I simplified the parser and now it succeeds:

> As a note about style: there's no reason ever to
>
> - use C style casts (they're dangerous)
> - write a loop with goto (considered harmful)
> - use cryptic variable names (r, r2?)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd0f6e145c82ab98)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/version.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace client::parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    //const auto entry_point = skip(space)[ ascii::cntrl ];
    const auto entry_point = ascii::cntrl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    std::cout << "Spirit X3 version: " << SPIRIT_X3_VERSION << "\n";

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 0x7f; ++i) {
        auto from_x3  = parse(&i, &i + 1, client::parser::entry_point);
        auto from_std = !!std::iscntrl(i);

        if (from_x3 != from_std) {
            std::cout << "0x" << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(i) << "\tx3:" << from_x3 << "\tstd:" << from_std << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```

Prints simply

```
Spirit X3 version: 3000
Done
```

With the "bad line" commented in instead:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c56a68d230b44616)</kbd>**

```
Spirit X3 version: 3000
0x09    x3:false    std:true
0x0a    x3:false    std:true
0x0b    x3:false    std:true
0x0c    x3:false    std:true
0x0d    x3:false    std:true
Done
```

Comment: Is there certainty that for the 2nd argument to parse, &i + 1 is always a valid address?

Comment: Yes. You cannot dereference it, but the address is valid for comparison. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086372/how-to-compare-pointers/9086675#9086675