# What does the following code do in cpython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

I was learning cpython internals(especially how `is` operator is implemented) and came across the following opcode implementation for `IS_OP` in [ceval.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5977a7989d49c3e095c7659a58267d87a17b12b1/Python/ceval.c#L3294)

```
case TARGET(IS_OP): {
   PyObject *right = POP();
   PyObject *left = TOP();
   int res = (left == right)^oparg;
   PyObject *b = res ? Py_True : Py_False;
   ...
}
```

I know the first two statements `pop` the operands from the stack.

```
PyObject *right = POP();
PyObject *left = TOP();
```

But my question is related to the following statement:

```
int res = (left == right)^oparg;
```

In my understanding `is` operator in python compares object identity, In other terms it will check whether both the objects are pointing to the same object. So my question is, only the following code is sufficient to check the [object identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9099485/6699447)?, Why the actual implementation again apply an exlcusive OR(`^`) with  `oparg`?

```
int res = (left == right)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IS_OP` op code is used for *both* `is` and `is not`. The `^oparg` flips the result of the comparison when `oparg` is `1` (for `is not`) and leaves it alone when it's `0` (for `is`), so the same bytecode can handle both cases branchlessly just by tweaking the `oparg` (in `dis` output, `is` is `IS_OP 0`, `is not` is `IS_OP 1`).

Comment: Ha yes, I just disassembled both `is` and `is not`. Both have the same opcode `IS_OP` and only difference in `oparg`. Thank you for the answer.