# Locking safety of datastructure

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, mutex

I have a data structure with:

- Multiple items 'A'.
- Each `A` has multiple items `B`. Each `B` is linked to exactly 1 `A`.
- Each `B` has multiple items `C`. Each `C` is linked to exactly 1 `B`.

For a local search algorithm i need to modify this datastructure from multiple threads.
The amount of `A` items is very large. The goal is to have each thread lock two `A` items, modify them, and unlock them.

An issue is that the selection of these operators is biased based on `C` items. Such that two `A` items need to be locked corresponding to `C` items.

My current approach is:

- Select (biased) two `C` items `c1` and `c2`.
- Store which `A`, `a1` and `a2`, they belong to (indirectly via their linked `B` item)
- Lock `a1` and `a2`.
- Check if `c1` and `c2` are still planned on `a1` and `a2`. If so, `a1` and `a2` can be mutated.

Would such an approach require any part of this data structure to be atomic or any other extra synchronization? I've made a toy example below.

---

### Edit

During mutation each `C` must always stay pointing to a `B` which must always point to an `A` locked by the mutating thread.

The mutation can change B.a and C.b within this constraint. For simplicity of the question create/destroy of A and B can be ignored.

A mutation function and some control loop has been added the example.

---

### Edit 2

It seems b->a and c->b must be atomic to ensure visibility. Otherwise the variable changes are not guaranteed to be visible at the check.

---

```
struct B;
struct C;

struct A {
    std::mutex mtx; // this lock is for A including its children
    std::vector<B*> b;
};
struct B {
    A* a;
    std::vector<C*> c;
};
struct C {
    B* b;
};

struct Instance
{
    // assume a & b have reserved space enough to never reallocate
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::vector<B> b;
    std::vector<C> c;
    std::vector<std::pair<C*, C*>> c_pairs;
};

struct Lock
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> a1, a2;
    std::pair<C*, C*> c_pair;
};

Lock try_get_locked_pair(const Instance& instance)
{
    const auto c_pair = instance.c_pairs[0 /* random number */];

    auto* a1 = c_pair.first->b->a;
    auto* a2 = c_pair.second->b->a;

    if (a1 == a2)
    {
        return { .c_pair = {nullptr, nullptr} };
    }

    if (std::unique_lock lk_a1{ a1->mtx, std::defer_lock }; lk_a1.try_lock())
    {
        // any threads that modify c_pair.first->b->a needs to have a lock on BOTH
        // the old and new value of b->a
        // we currently have a lock on 'a1'
        // thus no thread can change it to or from 'a1'
        // so if we get that b->a is 'a1', it cannot be changed to or from 
        // this value by another thread since the moment we got the lock
        // aka: any other thread modifying b->a while we also compare it true to a1, 
        // implies that thread must have the lock on a1 => contradition
        if (a1 == c_pair.first->b->a)
        {
            if (std::unique_lock lk_a2{ a2->mtx, std::defer_lock }; lk_a2.try_lock())
            {
                if (a2 == c_pair.second->b->a)
                {
                    return { std::move(lk_a1), std::move(lk_a2), c_pair };
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return { .c_pair = {nullptr, nullptr} };
}


void attempt_some_mutator(const Instance& instance)
{
    const auto lock = try_get_locked_pair(instance);
    if (!lock.c_pair.first)
    {
        return;
    }

    auto* a1 = lock.c_pair.first->b->a;
    auto* a2 = lock.c_pair.second->b->a;

    std::vector<C*> all_c;
    const auto collect_all_c_and_clear_c = [&](A* a)
    {
        for (B* b : a->b)
        {
            for (C* c : b->c)
            {
                all_c.push_back(c);
            }
            b->c.clear();
        }
    };
    collect_all_c_and_clear_c(a1);
    collect_all_c_and_clear_c(a2);

    const auto reconstruct_c_on_b = [&]() {
        for (auto* c : all_c)
        {
            c->b->c.push_back(c);
        }
    };

    if (all_c.size() <= 2)
    {
        reconstruct_c_on_b();
        return;
    }

    const auto evaluate_insert = [&](A* a, C* c) -> std::pair<B*, int>
    {
        for (auto* b : a->b)
        {
            /* ... code that evaluate the feasability and cost delta for adding c to b ... */
            const bool feasible = true;
            const int cost = 0;
            if (feasible)
            {
                return { b, cost };
            }
        }
        return { nullptr, 0 };
    };

    for (auto* c : all_c)
    {
        auto [b1, cost1] = evaluate_insert(a1, c);
        auto [b2, cost2] = evaluate_insert(a2, c);

        if (b1 && (!b2 || cost1 < cost2))
        {
            b1->c.push_back(c);
        }
        else if (b2)
        {
            b2->c.push_back(c);
        }
        else // infeasible
        {
            reconstruct_c_on_b();
            return;
        }
    }

    auto apply = [&](A* a)
    {
        for (B* b : a->b)
        {
            for (C* c : b->c)
            {
                c->b = b;
            }
        }
    };

    apply(a1);
    apply(a2);
}

void loop(const Instance& instance)
{
    // ... not really local search, but tests the mutator datastructure ...
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    for (int i = 0, n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i < n; ++i)
    {
        futures.push_back(std::async(i == 0 ? std::launch::deferred : std::launch::async, [&](){
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            {
                attempt_some_mutator(instance);
            }
        }));
    }
    for (auto& token : futures)
    {
        token.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't answer if atomics are possible, without knowing exactly the type of mutation, but nothing *requires* atomics. Atomics are just one way of synchronizing that's faster than locks.

Comment: Can we assume that objects are never added or removed from `Instance`? Otherwise, you end up with dangling pointers.

Comment: @MooingDuck I assume: `std::swap(a1, a2)` if  `a1 > a2` to create a stable locking order solves the issue you have in mind?

Comment: I deleted that comment, since I realized you're using `try_lock`, so don't have to worry about deadlocks

Comment: "Atomics are just one way of synchronizing that's faster than locks." - not necessarily; you still invoke memory barrier penalties.  If you need to alter more than 1 value atomically, you may find it's better to use mutexes.  (Saw it benchmarked on a conference talk somewhere)

Comment: @MooingDuck In practice the code may create and destroy `A` and `B` items. My solution was to store "deleted" objects in an extra list and never deallocate the objects. (Using them first when new A or B items are needed)

Comment: You can also have a look at reader writer locks. std::shared_mutex, std::shared_lock/std::unique_lock. So you can have multiple threads reading and only one writing

Comment: " The amount of A items is very large" - I'd probably shy away from using a vector; something akin to a B-tree or hashmap would probably be more suitable

Comment: @MooingDuck Based on your first comment I've added an invariant at the end of the post that must hold during mutation.

Comment: @Aedoro *I assume: `std::swap(a1, a2)` if `a1 > a2` to create a stable locking order*  Under which C++ specification?  See [**How to compare pointers?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086372/how-to-compare-pointers)

Comment: @Aedoro: if code can crreate and destroy `A` and `B` items, then you can't both store them in a `vector<T>` and also keep pointers to them. You either need `vector<T>` + offsets, or `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` + pointers.

Comment: @Den-Jason: More clearly: atomics are faster, but only synchronize single values.  If you need to synchronize multiple values, then atomics are not really a functional model, and one must use a lock.

Comment: Wait, if A and B can be added removed, and I see checks that `a1 == c_pair.first->b->a`... does that mean that `C.b` and `B.a` are *mutable*? If so, then those need locks too, guarding reads and writes.

Comment: There's way too many details missing for us to be able to tell you what you need.

Comment: @MooingDuck *since I realized you're using try_lock, so don't have to worry about deadlocks*  If both `a1` and `a2` refer to the same object, assuming some sort of retry that could turn into an infinite loop when the second `try_lock` fails...  *way too many details missing* indeed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `a1` and `a2` are checked to not be equal.

Comment: @MooingDuck I've updated the question with an example mutator. And for ease of the question assume no A/B create or destroy happens. (Theoretically the `vector<A>` and `vector<B>` can initialize as the amount of `C` items, and objects remain empty instead of deleted)

Comment: @Aedoro But you're doing that comparison without any locking.  If any `b->a`  value can change, that comparison is meaningless because it's a race condition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle They are stored as local variables. If the local variables are different, then `b->a` changing has no effect on that. And after locking i check if both `b->a` are still equal to the local variables, which were different so both `b->a` must be different. At least that is my reasoning.

Comment: @Aedoro `B->a` is not an atomic value, and it's not protected by any synchronization mechanism.  If any `B->a` can be changed by another thread, *any* thread evaluating any `B->a` value is a potential race condition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the `a1 == c_pair.first->b->a` comparison happens after `a1` is locked. So IF it succeeds `b->a` cannot be changed by another thread since that thread would need a lock on `a1`? This is kind of the insecurity i had in the code that made me start questioning if this works. So if you could help me understand why it doesn't work that would answer my question.

Comment: @Aedoro That's not relevant.  Again - if *any* `b->a` value can be changed by a thread, *all* `b->a` evaluations are potential race conditions. In `try_get_locked_pair()`, both `auto* a1 = c_pair.first->b->a;` and `auto* a2 = c_pair.second->b->a;` *are vulnerable to race conditions*  Locking `a` provides no protection at all for `b->a`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Do you have enough information to suggest a solution? I'm having difficulty finding an interleaving of the code that breaks it. Do i need a mutex on both c->b and b->a? and hold both mutexes when evaluating if the `a` is still the one that is locked?

Comment: @Aedoro Detailed solutions depend on actual, specific uses.  Note in my earlier comments I stated "*if* any `b->a` can change".  Mooing Duck said it earlier - there's really not enough detail here.  For something complex like this, I'd personally start with something simple, like a single global read/write lock on the entire data structure.  Benchmark that - thoroughly.  If it's fast enough, you're done.  Just because you think you have "too many transactions" for that to work doesn't mean it's true.  Today's hardware can be surprisingly fast.

Comment: It’s not just about “interleaving”: even one load of one value is a race if any other thread might be writing it concurrently.  If(!) that’s the only problem, you can use relaxed atomic operations to make that safe, but verifying that safety usually requires extremely careful algorithm design.

Comment: @DavisHerring Nobody has acually given me a reason why the reasoning (in comments in the toy example after locking) is incorrect. It doesnt break due to race conditions as far as i can tell. Due to changing b->a from or to a1 beeing impossible.